# How to dynamical specify table fields name in objectDB on any other DB

Tags: java, jpa, orm, object-oriented-database, objectdb

I am using `objectdb` with `jpa2`. I want to let my users specify the fields of my entity. How do I do that?

For example say I have an entity named `Animal` and I want the user to be the one specifying the name of the fields, all `Strings`. How would I do that? The user can be passing me a csv file with the name of the fields such as `name`, `owner`.

Comment: Define your problem better. You have a class and want to define the columns in the datastore? (JPA allows you to specify column names), or you don't have a class and want to generate a class with the fields the user defines? (nothing to do with JPA)

Comment: @DataNucleus I mean the first one: I have a class with no fields (i.e. columns) except maybe an id field. And I need to let the user define the field/column name and then add records (i.e. rows) to the table. How does JPA allow that? Can you show a code snippet?

Comment: If you have a class with no fields then adding fields is nothing to do with JPA. JPA relies on the class existing with its fields and objects of that class are persisted. You seem to be talking about updating a class definition to add fields, and then persist it ... thats outside the scope of JPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a Map as a persistent field in the Animal class, putting values dynamically  in that map.

This, however, could be less efficient than using ordinary persistent fields.

Alternatively you can also generate entity classes dynamically using a special library (such as cglib, ASM, javassist, arch4j).